# kendo datepicker depth year last day

Tags: datepicker, kendo-ui

I am trying to initialize a Kendo "datepicker" with the following options:

```
$("#elementid").kendoDatePicker({
    //... 
    depth: "year"
});
```

When I change month in the widget I would like to set in my view model the last day of the selected month (not, as by default, the first one).

For instance: by selecting "January" the datepicker is set on "01/01/2013", but I would like it to return "31/01/2013" (the last day).

Does somebody know how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define you `kendoDatePicker` as:

```
$("#elementid").kendoDatePicker({
    ...
    depth : "year",
    change: function (e) {
        var val = this.value();
        this.value(new Date(val.setMonth(val.getMonth() + 1, 0)));
    }
});
```

We handle the `change` event and use JavaScript for calculating the last day of the chosen date.